# Another error when installing RMySQL in Windows 7

Tags: r, windows, rmysql

I am trying to install RMySQL on Windows 7 using R version 2.15.1.
and I followed the instructions from http://www.ahschulz.de/2013/07/23/installing-rmysql-under-windows/ and another StackOverflow posts but I get this error over and over:

```html
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in setClass("MySQLDriver", contains = "DBIDriver", slots = list(Id = "integer")) : 
  unused argument(s) (slots = list(Id = "integer"))
Error : unable to load R code in package 'RMySQL'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'RMySQL'
* removing 'C:/Users/barney/Documents/R/win-library/2.15/RMySQL'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command 'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.1/bin/x64/R CMD INSTALL -l "C:/Users/barney/Documents/R/win-library/2.15"   C:\Users\barney\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpopPnLh/downloaded_packages/RMySQL_0.10.1.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RMySQL’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
 ‘C:\Users\barney\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpopPnLh\downloaded_packages’
```

Can you please help in solving this ? Thanks.